# Check if number is in between two numbers with increments

Tags: php, time

I have a time string and also a range of time with increment.

```
$start = strtotime('10:00:00');
$end = strtotime('23:30:00');
$increment = 30;

$given = strtotime('10:20:00');

if(if number lands on an incremented number) {
    echo 'success'
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

In the example, I want to see if `$given` falls on one of the incremented times between `$start` and `$end`. Incremented time means add the `$increment` to the `$start` until we get to `$end`.

So in the example code above, the following numbers are the only numbers that should pass the check:

```
10:00:00
10:30:00
11:00:00
11:30:00
12:00:00
12:30:00
13:00:00
13:30:00
14:00:00
14:30:00
15:00:00
15:30:00
...
23:30:00
```

In this case, `$given` = 10:20:00 so it does not pass the check. I **don't** want to use a for loop. I want to see if there is any math like checking for the remainder `%` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `%` for this.

First you'll need to convert your increment to seconds.

```
$increment *= 60;
```

Then you can find the answer by checking that

1. The given time is less than the end time, and
2. The difference between the given time and the start time can be evenly divided by increment (i.e. difference % increment == 0)

```
if ($given <= $end && 0 == ($given - $start) % $increment) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: If I already check if `$given <= $end`, can i just remove that part in the if statement? What would be the "fail" version of it first? Just check for `if(0 != ($given - $start) % $increment)` ?

Comment: Yes, if you've already checked that part you shouldn't need to repeat that. And that does look right for checking for fail first. You could actually omit the `0 != ` part, since any nonzero result will evaluate as true.

Comment: Thank you! I had everything right on my end except for the increment * 60

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to create a range with increment, from start to end and see if given is found in that array:

```
if(in_array($given, range($start, $end, $increment * 60))) {
    echo 'success';
} else {
    echo 'fail';
}
```

Comment: Wow very clever!